# How to use resample while keeping the missing dates

Tags: python, pandas

Hello I have the following database:

```
        name_normalized method
day     
2020-01-06  o2 mega searchNotes
2020-01-06  adiral  searchPatients
2020-01-06  adiral  searchPatients
2020-01-06  o2 mega searchPatients
2020-01-06  adiral  searchPatients
```

```
.tail()
```

```
2020-12-31  vyana medical   searchPatients
2020-12-31  vyana medical   searchNotes
2020-12-31  vyana medical   searchPatients
2020-12-31  vyana medical   searchPatients
2020-12-31  vyana medical   searchPatients
```

My job is simply to count per month how many methods are done for each title

For this I did naturally:

```
rep_month = Only2020_PPC.groupby(['name_normalized','method']).resample("M")['method'].count()
rep_month = rep_month.unstack('method', fill_value=0)
rep_month = rep_month.reset_index()
```

But by checking that all the companies had 12 repetitions for the 12 months, it turns out that not:

```
rep_month['name_normalized'].value_counts().tail()
```

```
...
atlas medical             12
o2 a dom                  11
arar soins a domicile     11
gep sante reunion          9
eole medical               5
gep sante                  1
```

After verification like this:

```
Only2020_PPC[Only2020_PPC['name_normalized']=='eole medical'].resample('M')['method'].value_counts()

day         method        
2020-04-30  searchNotes       6
            searchPatients    6
2020-05-31  searchNotes       1
            searchPatients    1
2020-08-31  searchPatients    1
```

As the company began its activity in the middle of the year, it does not take into account the dates before in the resample, but I want it to do so, I want it to go to the beginning of 2020 like the other companies until the end of 2020 and not just the period in which it has its activity.

I would like to add the dates of each month with 0 for the count for companies like this.

Example:

```
 day         method
2020-01-30  searchNotes       0
            searchPatients    0 
2020-02-29  searchNotes       0
            searchPatients    0 
2020-03-31  searchNotes       0
            searchPatients    0     
2020-04-30  searchNotes       6
            searchPatients    6
2020-05-31  searchNotes       1
            searchPatients    1
2020-06-30  searchNotes       0
            searchPatients    0
2020-07-31  searchNotes       0
            searchPatients    0  
2020-08-31  searchPatients    1
.......
```

how can i do it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As an option, `unstack` by day with `fill_value=0` and `stack` it back:

```
rep_month = Only2020_PPC.groupby(
    ['name_normalized','method']).resample('M')['method'].count()

# unstack by day with fill_value=0 and stack it back
rep_month = rep_month.unstack('day', fill_value=0).stack('day')

rep_month = rep_month.unstack('method', fill_value=0)
rep_month = rep_month.reset_index()
```

Output (based on the data given in the question):

```
method name_normalized        day  searchNotes  searchPatients
0               adiral 2020-01-31            0               3
1               adiral 2020-12-31            0               0
2              o2 mega 2020-01-31            1               1
3              o2 mega 2020-12-31            0               0
4        vyana medical 2020-01-31            0               0
5        vyana medical 2020-12-31            1               4
```

Comment: So I found it using your code, I changed one line and it passed ;) thank you the answer was not so hard in the end